# Windows 10 will not install on new PC build no matter what I try

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, bios

Yesterday I built a PC and it turns on and everything is recognized in the BIOS. However I CANNOT get Windows 10 to install.

I bought a disc drive and tried to install that way. Once I press install, it says that a "Media Driver for this PC cannot be found" so I figured that I would create a bootable USB.

I have created TWO USBs with the Windows Media Creation Tool. Both are formatted as FAT32. I can see it listed on the boot menu as "UEFI: Sandisk Partition 1". When I select it, the screen flashed the MOBO logo and shows the boot menu again. Nothing happens.

I have messed with all the BIOS setting. I changed it to UEFI only. I have made sure Secure Boot is off. What further ideas do you have?

EDIT: USB never ended up working, but installing via disk did work after connecting the disk drive to a new SATA port.

Comment: @Wasif_Hasan - That will not work..

Comment: @CodyLucas - Why exactly did you disable Secure Boot?  I would try using Rufus to create the installation media using the appropriate configuration to create a UEFi compatible installation media.

Comment: @Ramhound It is disabled by default on most motherboards, but most troubleshooting suggestions suggest disabling it too.

Comment: @John Yes, they are modern parts used all the time in common builds. The MOBO is an MSI Z-390, Intel i5-9600k processor

Comment: Secure Boot should be enabled unless you have a specific reason to disable it.  I have never encountered a motherboard where Secure Boot was disabled by default while in UEFI mode.  I have worked with hundreds of motherboards over the years.

Comment: @Ramhound I will try enabling it, but once you switch the BIOS to UEFI, it is disabled by default.

Comment: Legacy Mode doesn't support Secure Boot at all.  As I suggested, you should also use Rufus, using the recommended UEFI compatible settings.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar issue to you (posted it recently) and I had tried literally every possible solution to get it to work and nothing did. What I found out is that the recently released Windows 10 version 2004 just didn't boot on my hardware when used to make a bootable USB. So I used the previous version, 1909, with the same exact USB and BIOS settings and it worked. No idea what the specific problem was, aside from Microsoft doing something that borked it for my hardware.

You can use https://tb.rg-adguard.net/ to find a previous iso; however, I used [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to download and create the bootable usb. In order to download ISOs with Rufus, you need to make sure to enable automatic updates (for reasons explained in its [FAQ](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Help_I_dont_see_the_ISO_download_button)). Version 1909 - 19H2 should work, if your issue is the same as mine.

Before doing all this though, it might be useful to create a bootable usb of something like Ubuntu just to do a sanity check to ensure it isn't a formatting/UEFI issue. If it boots correctly, then what I've written should be the solution.